# Can Lua support Data URLs?

Tags: lua, base64

In LUA, you can load HTTP request using Loadstrings, which grab the data from any link.

Ive noticed these "Loadstrings" are rather annoying to lookup on the internet due to the large community of "roblox hackers" who use these loadstring scripts.

So its kind of hard to find... relavant... information

So I want to ask the people here, can I support a DataURL in my lua loadstring? Im running a simple lua environment with no plugins. (Basically I want to be able to load external scripts using a small "base64 webpage" that grabs data from another site, but always has a backup offline key if the online site goes down, hence being a data URL)

Comment: Could you provide an example? As far as I could find out, Lua's `loadstring` is only another name for eval() and has nothing to do with HTTP at all...

Comment: @grawity Ah i see, Well Im relatively new to lua, but its just a side skill I want to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is certainly possible to use loadstring to run Lua code from an external source it is not very good practice. It is generally unsafe to execute arbitrary code from the internet. If the server providing these files gets hacked all of the clients will be compromised. The second problem is that any code coding from server could fail if the client is running an older version, so it will be a nightmare to update and keep things in sync. A better approach is to send pure data from the server. You don't want your server to know anything about the client side. If you absolutely have to use loadstring then at least make sure it's sandboxed using setfenv:

```
function saferload(sz, env)
  local f = pcall(loadstring, sz)
  if not f then
    return
  end
  env = env or {}
  setfenv(f, env)
  return pcall(f) or env
end
```

You don't need to encode anything in base64. Just make sure your server headers are correct. In PHP that would look like:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

In regards to your DataURLs question, note that you can fetch binary data from the server too (in such case you don't need loadstring). Once you have fetched your file from the server you can save it in the AppData directory and update it when necessary.